# How do I remove the space before the first item and after the last item of an enumerate list inside a longtable?

Tags: spacing, lists, longtable, enumerate

I have several longtables in one document and they all have a fairly big gap before the first item and after the last item of every enumerate-list. Does anyone know how to get rid of that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{10cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{test} & \textbf{test}\\
    \hline
    \hline
    test          &  
       \begin{enumerate}
          \item test
          \item test
       \end{enumerate} \\
    \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly embed the enumerate environment inside a `minipage` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{10cm}}\hline
\textbf{test} & \textbf{test}   \\\hline\hline
test          &  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item test
      \item test
   \end{enumerate} 
  \end{minipage}
  \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But that result is a bit unsatisfactory.  Adding a bit of spacing before and after can make a better presentation.  This can be done by changing the parameters that control the enumerate environment.  The `enumitem` package allows easier control.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{10cm}}\hline
\textbf{test} & \textbf{test}   \\\hline\hline
test          &  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
     \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0.25ex,leftmargin=*]
        \item test
        \item test
     \end{enumerate} 
     \vspace{0pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]